# PostgreSQL - Selecting count of unique values in one and two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

Firstly, I'd like to apologise for the ambiguous title (I promise to revise it once I'm actually aware of the problem I'm trying to solve!)

I have two tables, **player** and **match**, which look like the following:

**player:**

```
id name
-- ----
1  John
2  James
3  April
4  Jane
5  Katherine
```

**match:**

```
id winner loser
-- ------ -----
1  1      2
2  3      4
```

Records in the **match** table represent a match between two players, where the **id** column is generated by the database, and the values in the **winner** and **loser** columns reference the **id** column in the **player** table.

I want to run a query which spits out the following:

```
player.id player.name total_wins total_matches
--------- ----------- ---------- -------------
1         John        1          1
2         James       0          1
3         April       1          1
4         Jane        0          1
5         Katherine   0          0
```

I currently have a query which retrieves total_wins, but I'm not sure how to get the total_matches count on top of that.

```
select p.id, p.name, count(m.winner)
from player p left join match m on p.id = m.winner
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
select p.id, p.name, 
       sum(case when m.winner = p.id then 1 end ) as total_wins,
       count(m.id) as total_matches
from player p 
left join match m on p.id in ( m.winner, m.loser )
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to return the correct results! Is `p.id in ( m.winner, m.loser )` the equivalent of `p.id = m.winner AND p.id = m.loser`?

Comment: Also, I just had to modify the case statement to read `case when m.winner = p.id then 1 else 0 end` so 0 would be displayed for players with no wins - FYI for anyone else with the same question.

Comment: No, `p.id in ( m.winner, m.loser )` is the same as `p.id = m.winner OR p.id = m.loser`, that is `OR` not `AND`

Answer (score 1):

One method splits the `match` match table, so you have a single row for each win and loss.  The rest is just a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select p.id, p.name, coalesce(sum(win), 0) as win, count(m.id) as total_matches
from player p left join
     (select match, winner as id, 1 as win, 0 as loss from match
      union all
      select match, loser as id, 0 as win, 1 as loss from match
     ) m
     on p.id = m.id
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! This query works but I'm getting a null value for player 5 wins instead of 0.

Comment: @disposedtrolley . . . Just use `coalesce()`.